# How can I run some initialization code with vue.js before the components get mounted?

Tags: vue.js

In my main `App.vue`, I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  mixins: [logoutMixin],
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log('do initialization stuff')
  }
};
</script>
```

And in a separate `Settings.vue`, I have:

```
export default {
  name: "Settings",
  data() {
    console.log(this.$User);
    return {
      User: this.$User
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted");
  }
};
```

Somehow the `data` gets run before the `App`'s `beforeCreate`. Is there some top level place I can execute initialization code?

Comment: you know that there is a `beforeMount()` lifecycle hook

Comment: Still - the `Settings` component has the `data()` function called before the `App` components `beforeMount`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you share a working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)?

Comment: Did you mean `console.log(this.$User)` runs before `console.log('do initialization stuff')`?

Comment: Yes - that's precisely the problem

Comment: Cannot reproduce this ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-lc1de

Comment: @Shamoon I would put it in `main.js` before mounting the root component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Vue Parent and Child lifecycle`, it will execute code `Parent's created() => Child's created() => Child mounted() => Parent mounted()`.

In your case, `App.vue` is parent component, `Settings.vue` is child component. So you can initialize data in `beforeCreate()` or `create()` hooks in `App.vue` component. But don't put any code before `return {}` in `data()` parts. Since Vue can not guarantee the execute order out of `Vue lifecycle`.

Comment: _"But don't put any code before  `return {}` in `data()` parts"_  why not?

Comment: I means if you want to execute code ***in order*** (`Parent component => Child component`). You should not put code before `return {}` in `data()` parts. Instead, put code in `Vue lifecycle hook` (`created()` or `mounted()`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in `main.js/ts` file before mount the main component:

```
doInitializationStuff()

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In the case of async initialization (be careful and don't use it for long async functions):

```
doInitializationStuff().then(() => {
 new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```